# Copy and replace values in numpy array.. nans will be nan but other values will be zero

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a numpy array which I want to copy to another numpy array and replace all values to zero except the nan values. Can you help please?

Comment: `b = a.copy(); b[~np.isnan(b)] = 0`

Comment: Thanks! Just adding a bit, what if I have another array called c, and I want to copy the values from c to b if the value in b is nan? Like, using the specific index where the value is nan.

Comment: `b[np.isnan(b)] = c[np.isnan(b)]` or `b = np.where(np.isnan(b), c, b)` or to do everything at once from `a`: `b = np.where(np.isnan(a), c, 0)`

Comment: i think the `np.where` solution is the cleanest and probably fastest too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `numpy.where`.

Data from @GrantWilliams.

**Problem 1**

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan])
c = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])

res1 = np.where(np.isnan(a), np.nan, 0)

array([  0.,   0.,  nan,   0.,   0.,  nan])
```

**Problem 2**

```
res2 = np.where(np.isnan(a), c, 0)

array([ 0,  0, 12,  0,  0, 15])
```

Comment: I like your solution to problem 2 quite a bit. np.where is really clean

Comment: @GrantWilliams, Thanks - yours is more easily adaptable to in-place operations. But either works for OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set a 0 array then i guess there is no need to copy the original array. Just make an array of zeros and set the appropriate indices to nan.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan])
b = np.zeros(a.shape)
b[np.isnan(a)] = np.nan
```

outputs

```
>>> b
[ 0.  0. nan  0.  0. nan]
```

edit: now that you've updated the problem you can use this instead:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan])
b = np.zeros(a.shape)
c = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
b[np.isnan(a)] = c[np.isnan(a)]

print(b)
```

outputs

```
>>> b
[ 0.  0. 12.  0.  0. 15.]
```

feel free to change the dtype to int if thats what youre using as well